# How do I configure a session cookie in Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, azure, cookies, azure-functions

Every Web server framework has the concept of sessions, where the server uses a cookie to identify logged-in users.  I'm looking at migrating an existing Web API server to work on Azure Functions, but I can't find anything on how it handles sessions, either in the documentation or on StackOverflow or other third-party resources.

Any searches I do tend to return a bunch of stuff that's not at all relevant, mixed with a bunch of authentication stuff about getting the user to sign in with a 3rd party provider such as Microsoft, Facebook, or Google.  But I already have a working login system, and also the client is a SPA, so navigating off of it to a third-party login page is a bad idea.

So I'm finding myself quite frustrated at not finding any good answer to what ought to be an extremely simple question: *how does session cookie management work in Azure Functions?*  (Specifically, C# precompiled HTTP trigger v2 functions.  More specifically, I need to be able to configure a custom name for the session cookie, set the value of the cookie, retrieve the value of the cookie, and drop the cookie if the user logs out.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary use cases for Azure Functions are stateless, and sessions are a bit against this principle. You can probably emulate it yourself by using `Request.Cookies` and `Response.Cookies` but ASP.NET features aren't directly applicable in Functions.

Comment: So I have to roll my own session cookies.  Charming.

Comment: Cookies are so 2000-ish :trollface:

Comment: @MikhailShilkov - Cookies may be 2000-ish, but they are still widely used.  Lets say you want to store content on a redirect, but you don't want to create a database, because the content truly is for a specific session.  I don't want to pay Redis or a DB for something that is only going to persist within a session.